# combine sikulix with keyboard & mouse action recording software?

Tags: keyboard, mouse, sikuli, recorder

I wonder if I can record a keyboard + mouse action macro (let's say about 30 seconds of key strokes and mouse movements) and then ask sikuli to execute this macro by calling that macro somewhere within sikuli's script?

Comment: Some details are missing. How are you using Sikuli? Java? Jython? IDE? What is the nature of the script you want to execute? Is that exe file? Something else? Also, why won't you just create the same macro using Sikuli itself?

Comment: it is for a video game which is 3d. i found a solution which is to record my keyboard and mouse for like a minute or so with Jitlib software, then export that into an .exe and ask sikuli to run it when needed.

Comment: still didn't answer my questions

Comment: I am using sikuli IDE and the code is in Python. 
What I want is to create a macro, that will simulate the exact movements of my mouse as well as keystrokes, for about 1 minute. As far as I know, sikuli doesn't offer a record function, that would capture my mouse+keyboard for a specific amount of time. Of course I could code those movements, but it would take me days to do so. 
Therefore, I found Jitbit, which does the job of recording a macro, and is able to export it as a .exe. Then using sikuli, I run() that .exe when needed and everything works great :)

Thanks for your comment